# Ajax link after infinite scroll not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a bookshop with more then 100 books.
Through a search function I'm loading 10 books at the same time. When the user scrolls down the infinite Scroll function loads 10 new books (with ajax).

Next to every book title is a buy link. This is a ajax link for adding the book in the shopping cart.

```
<a href="/books/buy" onclick="return false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" id="book<?php echo $bookId;?>"></i></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click","#book<?php echo $bookId;?>",function(){
            $.ajax({url: "books/buy/<?php echo $bookId;?>", 
                        type:'post',
               })   });
</script>
```

The ajax link for the first books is working good. But the link for the books loaded with the infinite scroll is not working.

While I was trying to find a solution a noticed when I don't use a bookId, so all the icons have the same id, the ajax link is working but then I don't know which book was selected. 
And if I don't use the invite scroll everything works but then I have to load to many books at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a better way to do the listeners.

```
<a href="/books/buy/<?php echo $bookId;?>" id="book-link">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right></i>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click","#book-link", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({ 
            url: $(this).attr('href'), 
            type:'post',
        })
    });
</script>
```

You only need to load the script part once, when you load your page.

I hope it helps.